# Imprimir array en Ensamblador x86

Tags: ensamblador, imprimir

Cómo puedo hacer el siguiente código bien? casi no encuentro material de ensamblador y no sé como manejarlo, la idea era imprimir varios numeros, pero no sé cómo pasarlos ascii o qué es lo que se necesita para que no tener "violacion de segmento"

```
section .data
    lst dd 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
    len dd 10

section .text
global _start

_start:
    mov ecx, dword[len]   ; Carga la longitud de la lista en ECX
    mov rsi, 0          ;

print_loop:
    
    mov eax , dword [ lst +( rsi *4) ] 
    inc rsi
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1      ; salida estandar
    syscall                ; Realiza la syscall para imprimir el número

    loop print_loop        ; Continúa hasta que todos los números sean impresos

exit:
    mov rax, 60      ; syscall number for sys_exit
    xor rdi, rdi     ; exit status 0
    syscall          ; Realiza la syscall para salir del programa
```

Comment: Bienvenida. Estaría bien que aclares el sistema operativo y la arquitectura en uso.

Answer (score 1):

Sí hay material. La mayoría se encuentra en **inglés**.

De acuerdo al sistema operativo y la arquitectura del procesador programarás de una forma u otra. Deduzco que estás trabajando con **Linux** y la arquitectura **x86_64** así que intentaré orientarte respecto a eso.

---

Para comunicarte con el núcleo se utiliza la instrucción `syscall` y una [convención de llamadas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989/13419694), es decir, una manera de indicarle qué quieres hacer y los parámetros necesarios.

- El primer parámetro es el número de la función y se pasa mediante `rax`.
- El resultado de la función se devuelve también en `rax`.
- El resto de los parámetros se pasan en los registros `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `r10`, `r9` y `r8`.

En tu código se ve que quieres llamar a la función `write`, ya que cargas `1` en `rax` y luego se ejecuta `syscall`. Estás aplicando bien lo que acabo de mencionar.

Sin embargo, la función [`write`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) toma 3 parámetros y solo le estás pasando uno. Te falta la **cadena de caracteres** a imprimir y su tamaño, en ese orden.

Antes de poder imprimir un número necesitas convertirlo en una cadena.

Algunos tips:

- Puedes escribir en otro lenguaje y luego pensar cómo llevarlo a ensamblador.
- Puedes ver lo que genera el compilador con [`objdump`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) o [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/).
- Los dígitos en ASCII tienen valores consecutivos, permitiéndote convertir un número del 0 al 9 en un dígito fácilmente.

---

También debes tener en cuenta que hay *registros* que son parte de registros más grandes. Por ejemplo, `rax` es un registro de 64 bits, `eax` corresponde a sus 32 bits menos significativos y `ax` a los 16. Así como `ah` y `al` corresponden a los 8 más y menos significativos respectivamente.

Esta imagen de [un artículo de Medium](https://medium.com/@nafisanaznin24cse041/microprocessor-i-general-purpose-registers-31cd43f3d6bd) te ayudará a comprenderlo:

[image: Diagrama de registros]

Esto para mencionar que justo antes de la llamada al sistema cargas un valor en el registro `eax` y se pierde al cargar un valor en `rax`.

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a tus preguntas:

- Pasar los números a ASCII no es trivial. Es relativamente sencillo mostrar números hexadecimales ya que los puedes dividir en nibbles (bloques de 4bits) y procesarlos todos igual. En el código de más abajo te muestro como imprimir un digito hexadecimal. Como no especificas en que base quieres imprimir los números tomaré el caso más sencillo para no sacrificar la legibilidad del código.
- El segfault de tu programa es probablemente debido a que `syscall` modifica `RCX` y `R11` de tal forma que, al regresar de `syscall` el valor de `RCX` puede ser cualquier cosa y por ello tu bucle no termine cuando debería. Eventualmente acabarás accediendo a una dirección no permitida.

Te adjunto una sencilla modificación de tu programa con comentarios para imprimir los números de tu ejemplo (los cuales se pueden representar como un solo digito hexadecimal).

```
section .data
    lst dd 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ; Lista de números a imprimir
    msg db "0123456789ABCDEF"         ; Almacenamos los dígitos en una cadena
                                      ; que podemos pasar a la syscall directamente
    len equ 9                         ; El tamaño es una constante.

section .text
global _start

_start:
    xor r10,r10    ; r10 será nuestro contador. Lo inicializamos a cero
                   ; r10 no es modificado por `syscall`
print_loop:
    mov eax , DWORD [lst + 4*r10] 
    inc r10         ; Incrementamos el contador

    mov rdi, 1      ; stdout
    ; El valor que queremos imprimir es el caracter RAX-ésimo de msg
    lea rsi, [msg +rax] 
    mov rdx, 1      ; escribimos un caracter

    mov rax, 1      ; SYS_WRITE
    syscall         ; Realiza la syscall para imprimir el número
    
    cmp r10, len    ; Hemos impreso todos los caracteres?
    jnz print_loop  ; NO?, repetimos 

exit:
    mov rax, 60      ; syscall number for sys_exit
    xor rdi, rdi     ; exit status 0
    syscall          ; Realiza la syscall para salir del programa
```